# How can i skip appium server log from my eclipse console to txt file

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, appium, log4net-appender

How can I skip `appium` server log from my `eclipse` console to txt file?

I need only my program log on console and `appium` server log should be logged on txt file only

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run-> Run Configurations -> Common Tab --> Check file in Standard Input And Output File section

[Eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43y2m.png)

Comment: Syam, This solution skip the entire eclipse console to txt file. but what i need is - only the appium server console to be on txt file.

Comment: @Hashili did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the server log displayed on the console window

```
command.addArgument("--log-level" ,false);
command.addArgument("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `log` CLI now

```
appium --log /path/to/appium.log
```